# Multi step popup multi dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to poup a multi dimensional array from multiple SQL queryes, so in more than one step. I would like to make here the 2. column:

```
      $name=$r['Name'];
      $second_attribute=$r['sec'];

      while($i<$count_full){
          if($daily_namedb[$i] == $name){
            $daily_namedb[] = $second_attribute;
          }
          $i++;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
      $name=$r['Name'];
      $second_attribute=$r['sec'];

      while($i<$count_full){
          if($daily_namedb[$i] == $name){
            $daily_namedb[$i][] = $second_attribute;
          }
          $i++;
      }
```

Comment: "Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings"

Comment: It begins with a loop: while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))